# How correct stop timer threads in hibernate localsessionfactorybean?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, javabeans

I have spring web application and found that

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

creates 2 timer threads that don't stop after tomcat shutdown.

Does it possible to configure to stop these threads after tomcat received shutdown command or need use some kind of aspect?
Thanks.

Comment: Where are the timer threads created?

Comment: In local session bean - but I am not sure (when I cut off this bean - threads dissappear), for this reason I ask a question.

Comment: I don't see any Threads being created.  Can you edit your question and post a thread dump for them?